# Would have + past participle + had without if

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

I am reading a book for English languages learners, Oliver Twist, and there are two parts that surprise me. Both have the same form.
I have copied the text word for word:

> But the magistrate sentenced him to three months in  prison, with hard labour, and **the boy would have been taken away** to prison **had** it not been for the owner of the bookshop, who rushed into the office and at this point advanced towards the bench.

The second one:

> The fellow touched his hat with a smile, expecting something for his trouble; but the old gentleman looked at him with and expression of dislike, **and would have run away himself had not** a police officer at that moment made his way through the crowd and seized Oliver by the collar.

I understand what it means but I'm surprised because there is no "if" before "had".

For example, why isn't it written "and would have run away himself **if there** had not a police officer" or something like this in the second part?

Please, could you explain this to me? I can't find a rule about that.

Thank you so much.

Comment: We have a couple of dozen question on this subject: they're tagged [conditional-constructions] and [inversion], and [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional-constructions+inversion)'s a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In his book, *Practical English Usage* (261.5), Swan remarks that in literary and formal styles this is possible with certain auxiliary verbs: *if* is left out and *had*, for instance, is placed before the subject. If the rest of the sentence remains the same, the two are interchangeable except for the literary or formal overtones of the *if*-less version.

Furthermore, Swan adds that negatives aren't contracted in that case (*had I not* does not become *hadn't I*).

Let's take a look at the (somewhat abridged) examples from your question:

1. > ...and the boy would have been taken away to prison **had it not been for the owner of the bookshop**, who rushed...

The sentence above can be rephrased as follows:

> ...and the boy would have been taken away to prison **if it hadn't been for the owner of the bookshop**, who rushed...

---

2. > ...but the old gentleman looked at him with an expression of dislike, and would have run away himself **had not a police officer at that moment made his way through the crowd and seized**...

Again, we can rephrase the relevant parts in the following manner:

> ...but the old gentleman looked at him with an expression of dislike, and would have run away himself **if a police officer at that moment hadn't made his way through the crowd and seized**...

or

> ...but the old gentleman looked at him with an expression of dislike, and would have run away himself **if a police officer hadn't at that moment made his way through the crowd and seized**...

Note that in the rephrased sentences it was okay to use the contracted form, *hadn't*.